How to move config directory to `/opt/`
On Debian, I've moved the AppImage to /opt/nvim/ and made a custom init.lua there. The problem is that when I make an autoload/ directory next to it, neovim won't look for the plug.vim there. When I require("plug.vim") it looks only for .lua or .so files.
I also load nvim with -u /opt/nvim/init.lua.
A potential clue might be the information in :h runtimepath but the docs are very unclear. (Classic)

Could you give us more information about your folder hierarchy (small schema would help to identify init.lua, autorun, plugin, lua folders)?

@VivianDeSmedt I only had the files in my post. So the /opt/nvim/init.lua & /opt/nvim/autoload/plug.vim. I also open vim with /opt/nvim/nvim.appimage -u /opt/nvim/init.lua

I don’t think you can Lua-require a vimscript file, if that’s the problem

Do you still have something open in your question? How could we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

@VivianDeSmedt Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for :(. I don't want to change the XGD variables :(.

Thanks for your feedback! Note that you can change them only for the script that starts Neovim such that only Neovim is aware of the new values.

I would define the following environment variables before starting Neovim (normally i.e. not need to specify the -u parameter):
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/opt
XDG_DATA_HOME=/opt
XDG_STATE_HOME=/opt

More information with :help base-directories
Remark: If you don't want to change these environment variables for the global system you can creates a script that change them only for the Neovim child process:
nvim.sh:
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/opt
XDG_DATA_HOME=/opt
XDG_STATE_HOME=/opt
nvim $@


That's it. Thanks!

Thanks for the feedback :-)

An alias would be convenient too: alias nvim='XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/opt XDG_DATA_HOME=/opt XDG_STATE_HOME=/opt nvim'.
